# How to handle separated stock for a product bundle?

Tags: commerce, entities

Following the scenario that I want implement in my store. There are three products: A, B, C. My purpose is to sell two bundle composed by AB and BC. 
Each product has its stock: A x10, Bx5, Cx20. The bundle products are dependable by the stock of every single product so it will not possible to order more than 5 AB product (or BC product) because every time a bundle product is bought the stock of every single must descrease.

When a single product's stock runs out, every bundle product composed by that single product can't be sold.

Is there any way to achieve my purpose?

Answer (score 2):

I am the author and maintainer of the [Commerce Product Kit](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_product_kit) module which is close to your requirement.

> It provides a "field formatter" for the "product reference" or an
>   "entity reference" fields to add all the commerce products referenced that
>   field to the cart at once.

It also has support to the commerce stock module. If a product kit has 3 products in it (A, B, and C), and say one of them is out of stock (B), it is not added to the cart.

Not allowing *any product* to be added to cart even if one of the product from kit is not in stock makes sense and can be considered a good addition to the cart.

I have created a feature request in the issue queue for the same :
 [#2821442 : Disallow adding product kit to cart if one product is out of stock.](https://www.drupal.org/node/2821442)

While I do not have the time to implement it myself now, I would be happy to review any patches and make this a part of the module.